# Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Comment', but it does

Tags: typescript

```
{post?.comments?.map((comment) => (
  <div>{comment.text}</div>
))}
```

Post is type Post, comments is type [Comment].  Here are the type definitions from another file.  Unfortunately my project is too large to post all of it, and most is irrelevant to this problem anyways.  I can post anything else that is needed upon request.  I would also like to note that the code does not fail when executed, only annoying IDE complaints from Typescript that 'text' does not exist on type Comment.  The subreddit property on Post does not have this problem, interestingly enough.

```
type Comment {
  created_at: DateTime
  id: ID!
  post_id: ID
  text: String
  username: String
}

type Post {
  body: String
  created_at: DateTime
  id: ID!
  image: String
  subreddit_id: ID
  title: String
  username: String
  votes: [Vote]
    @materializer(
      query: "getVotesByPostId"
      arguments: [{ name: "post_id", field: "id" }]
    )
  comments: [Comment]
    @materializer(
      query: "getCommentsByPostId"
      arguments: [{ name: "post_id", field: "id" }]
    )
  subreddit: [Subreddit]
    @materializer(
      query: "getSubredditListById"
      arguments: [{ name: "id", field: "subreddit_id" }]
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type name to RedditComment fixed the problem.  I have no idea why.